# Example of REINFORCE implementation without neural nets

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

Do you know of any REINFORCE algorithm implementation that use other optimizer instead of neural networks? Every implementation I see around uses them (like https://medium.com/@thechrisyoon/deriving-policy-gradients-and-implementing-reinforce-f887949bd63), and as far as I know the algorithm does not exactly require its use.

Comment: Does a softmax or linear regression count? That *can* be viewed as a NN without hidden layers, but typically you would do some work on representation e.g. tile coding, and the behaviour of these approximators is often different to neural networks. Most of the pseudocode in e.g. Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction assumes a linear approximator

Comment: It does. I just checked in the book and it really gives a definition for the policy function parameterized by weights, which itself can use any of the function approximators that are defined in section 9.5 (didnt read it but understood the idea). However, seeing some actual code of a practical implementation of this would still be very helpful.